# Display sum of Pandas Dataframe in PyQt LineEdit

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, qlineedit

I have I a nicely working Pandas dataframe and I want to copy the sum of a column into the LineEdit of a PyQt application.

What I have so far is:

```
    sales = pd.read_excel ("Sales.xlsx" , parse_dates=['Data'] )

    purchase_patterns = sales [['Total','Data']]
    purchase_patterns = purchase_patterns.set_index("Data")
    resample = purchase_patterns.resample ('D' , how = sum)

    pandas_value = resample[-1:].sum()

    print pandas_value

    pyqt_value = str(pandas_value)
    today_stats = QtGui.QLineEdit ( self.dialog)
    today_stats.setText (pyqt_value)
```

The "print pandas_value" statement returns

```
Total 71.09
dtype: float64
```

This is what I also see in the QLineEdit.

How can I get just the the sum (71.09) to appear in the LineEdit?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display sum of Pandas Dataframe in PyQt LineEdit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183042/display-sum-of-pandas-dataframe-in-pyqt-lineedit)

Answer (score 1):

`pandas_value` is `Series` so you need `pandas_value[0]` to get first element.

```
pyqt_value = str(pandas_value[0])
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works perfectly. Can you maybe shortly explain what the parameter in brackets does? Is this sort of an index? I have changed it to [1] and it returns : out of bounds ....

Comment: As I said - it's `Series` (try `type(pandas_value)`) and `Series` keeps only one row/column of data - so it is like `list`. This `Series` has only one element so you can use only `[0]`.